# How to get a remote JPG from a URL using USER and Password?

Tags: java, android, httpclient, inputstream

i want to get a remote JPG file from a URL and have it into a Bitmap. I'm developing for Android, i have internet on the phone and internet permission on the manifest.

The problem is that the URL needs a user and a password.

I know how to get a remote image into a bitmap without password:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}
```

And i know how to get a XML String from a url with USER AND PASSWORD:

```
public String getXML(String url){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpResponse response; 
    try { 
         ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope(null,-1), 
                new org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials(MagazineStatus._username, MagazineStatus._password)); 

        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url)); 
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            try {                   
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  builder.append(line);        
            }catch(Exception ex) {Log.e("DBF Error",ex.toString());}                 
        }else { 
            response.getEntity().getContent().close(); 
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase()); 
        } 
    }catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {Log.e("ClientProtocolException @ at FPT",cpe.toString());} catch(Exception ex) {Log.e("Exception at FETCHPROJECTASK",ex.toString());} 
    return builder.toString();
}
```

So, i need to download a Bitmap from a url but using USER and PASSWORD, like in the XML method. But i dont know how to merge the sorce codes.

Please can someone help me to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are the images hosted? flicker.com?

Comment: Can you put sample output of XML string in your question itself. That would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really relevant but here's a suggestion. You may want to use a PNG file rather than a JPEG file because PNG does not lose it's quality when it's data is compressed (Android also prefers using PNG). This way, the view you have will look pretty much the same on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and to solve it, I inserted the following header in the http request:
Header: Authorization 
Value: "Basic "+Base64Coder.encodeString(user+":"+pass)

Base64Coder is a free class that helped me to transform the user+":"+pass string to Base64 format. You can download the code from several places in Internet.

About how to insert a new header in the http request, I used HttpPost and HttpGet objects, instead of HttpURLConnection. I don't know whether it can be done with HttpURLConnection. To set a header, you only have to use the method setHeader.

I'm including a link that shows how to use httpget.
http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by using your same task. You need to create another asyntask<> that will fetch image for you and return bitmap. I done this before too. Use this code for this..

```
Bitmap image = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
// param[0] would be replaced with your image path.
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("MalformedURLException",e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException",e.toString());
        }       
        return image;       
    }
```

Hope, again it will work for you.